# generate unique id based on a pattern

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table (say invoice), in which there's a primary key (auto-increment).
But I need another reference number, which should also be unique, and should be based on the following pattern.

```
INV-{Ymd}-{unique number for that day}
```

Where: 
INV - is contact prefix
{Ymd} - date in YYYMMDD format
{unique number for that day} - is serial number for that day.(should be auto increment, but should start from 0 every day.

Example

- INV-20160909-0001
- INV-20160909-0002
- INV-20160910-0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with same table No need to create another table or column.

Assume your column name is **reference_number** in **invoice** table.

First, Get the **latest record** from your table.(you can fetch it by **primary key** or **insertion date**)

```
$data=Invoice::find()->select('reference_number')->orderBy(['your_primary_key' => SORT_DESC])->one();

if($data) // record found
{
  $temp= explode('-',$$data['reference_number']); // devide data in array

  // compare with today's date,
  if((int)$temp[1]==(int)date('Ymd')) 
  {
    // if today's date match than increase number and create reference_number
    $reference_number="INV".date('Ymd').((int)$temp[2]+1);
  }
  else // reference_number is from old date so you can create from today's date
  {
  $reference_number="INV".date('Ymd')."0";
  }
}
else // record not found,(no record in your table)
{
  // you can directly create reference_number from today's date

  $reference_number="INV".date('Ymd')."0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample code i'm using to generate invoice id

```
$seq = Sequence::FindOne(['seq_id' => 'INV/AG', 'seq_name' => (int)date('ymd')]);
    if(is_null($seq))
    {
        $_seq = new Sequence();
        $_seq->seq_id = 'INV/AG';
        $_seq->seq_name = (int)date('ymd');
        $_seq->value = 0;
        $_seq->save();
        $model->trx_id = $_seq->seq_id . '/' . $_seq->seq_name . str_pad($_seq->value+1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    else {
        $seq->value += 1;
        $model->trx_id = $seq->seq_id . '/' . $seq->seq_name . str_pad($seq->value, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $seq->update();
    }
```

first, you need to create table sequence which contains seq_id, seq_name and value.
this format would generate ex: INV/AG/160917004

hope this answer your question.